# Why is innerHTML function not filling my div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen a ton of posts with similar problems, but none with the div structure I'm using.  I'm building a page with a navigation sidebar containing buttons that use the `innerHTML` function to fill the content div with different HTML pages.  I have wrapper classes and content classes, the called up HTML using the content class for formatting.

For some reason the HTML fills only a small portion of the content wrapper when called up via JavaScript.  But, when I copy the div from the called up HTML file and paste it directly into the content wrapper in the index file, I don't have this problem.  What is happening that would cause the `innerHTML` feature to limit the width/height of the called up div?

Here is an example of the sidebar/content HTML in the index file:

```
<div class="sidebar_wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
            <p><button type="button" onclick="load_bookings();">Manage Bookings</button></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content" class="content_wrapper">
</div>
```

Here is an example of the JavaScript function in the index file:

```
<script>
    function load_bookings() {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="bookings_home.html" ></object>';
    }
</script>
```

Here is an example of the HTML being loaded in from `bookings_home.html`:

```
<div class="content">
    <p align="center">Manage bookings</p>
</div>
```

Here are the four classes being referenced in the CSS file:

```css
.sidebar_wrapper {
    width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    opacity: 1;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(249,237,7,1) 0%,rgba(252,247,142,0.7) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    /*<!--background-color: rgb(249,237,7);*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    top: 11px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 85%;
}

.content_wrapper {
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content {
    overflow: scroll;
    color: black;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How it looks:

[image: Actual result]

How it should look, and how it does when I put the same div in directly in the index file:

[image: Expected result]

UPDATE #1

Here is the full code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=style.css>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function load_bookings() {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="bookings_home.html" ></object>';
    }
</script>

<div class="sidebar_wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
            <p><button type="button" onclick="load_bookings();">Manage Bookings</button></p>
    </div>      
</div>

<div id="content" class="content_wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the full code for the content html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=style.css>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<p align="center">Manage bookings</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the full code for the .css file:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.sidebar_wrapper {
width: 160px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
opacity: 1;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(249,237,7,1) 0%,rgba(252,247,142,0.7) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
top: 11px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
margin: 20px;
height: 85%;
}

.content_wrapper {
overflow: scroll;
background-color: white;
height: 100%;
width: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}

.content {
overflow: scroll;
color: black;
background-color: green;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: object{ width:100%; height:100%: }

Answer (score 1):

I tried an example  [JS FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and it works fine if you call your script before your html code.
Try calling this:

```
<script>
    function load_bookings() {
        document.getElementById("content").getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="bookings_home.html" ></object>';
    }
</script>
```

Before this:

```
<div class="sidebar_wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
            <p><button type="button" onclick="load_bookings();">Manage Bookings</button></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content" class="content_wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: Strange, I do have the script before the div html.  I'm wondering if there is some basic structural error in html similar to what you are saying.  Here is the full code for both html files:

Comment: Sorry, still learning how to post to Stack Overflow.  I put the code in the first update.  Sorry for the lack of tabulation...

Comment: Try replacing document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=... with document.getElementById("content").getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerHTML=...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because you have mixed the quotations in your statement of assignment.

When you say:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="bookings_home.html" ></object>';
```

The issue is that you stated off with a single quote (') and in that same statement you have some double quotes (") which might have confused the browser.

Use escape character for the double quotes: (backslash )

Do the following:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<object type=\"text/html\" data=\"bookings_home.html\" ></object>";
```

Comment: It's okay to mix the type of quotes. I personally will use single quotes for the outside and double quotes for all of the HTML attributes. All it does is make it so you don't have to escape them as in your example.

Comment: If your answer starts with "maybe", consider testing before posting it.